# Separate Image Into Specific Lines and Match to Images Python

Tags: python, image, opencv, python-imaging-library, scikit-image

I have a bunch of images, all of which look fairly similar to the one below:
[image: Example Route Tree]

In these images, the lines are distinct (at least to human eyes) but they intersect often. I am not very familiar with python image processing but I have heard opencv can be useful for these kinds of things. I would like to separate the lines somehow.

Furthermore, I would like to compare these images to the NFL route tree (this I would be able to separate into 9 different routes by hand to have 9 different images to compare to, so just imagine that):
[image: Basic NFL Route Tree]

The question really boils down to this: how do I separate out the distinct lines in the image (ex. 8 different lines for the example image from Mark Andrews), and then compare these lines to find which of my 9 route images is the nearest match?

If opencv is not the correct package for this, just let me know, and let me know if there is a package or packages that will allow me to do this. Thanks!